# Footer not appearing on localhost server

Tags: html, css, localhost

I am making a website and I ran it as a local file and the footer appeared but when I used localhost it didn't show the footer. I have already tried to change the height, make it visible, and inspect element. It seems that on the localhost server the footer is below the body but in the code of the footer is inside the body.

```
<footer align="center" id="footer">
    <div id="footer1"><br><br>
        <ul style="float: right; margin-right: 35%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="footerLinks">
            <h3 style="float: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Links</h3><br><br>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="footerLink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" class="footerLink">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" class="footerLink">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" class="footerLink">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" class="footerLink">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 style="float: left; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">About</h3><br><br>
        <p style="float: left; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 30%;">Description</p>

    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <p style="float: left; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">© copyright me</p>
        <p style="float: right; margin-right: 20%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Created by me</p>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #0B0C10;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#footerLinks {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footerLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C5C6C7;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Try clearing history if you had made changes to CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has definitely nothing to do with localhost, but either with the way you include the footer (filepath) or with your stylesheet, which you didn't post.

Nevertheless, since all of the elements in your footer are floats, I suggest to add `overflow: auto` to the `footer` element to make sure it wraps its floating contents, otherwise it might have height: 0...

Comment: Ok, I'll put the CSS in!

Comment: Good answer! I agree, this has nothing to do with the server being local.